# Measure height of react-native ref (ListView)

Tags: react-native, react-native-listview, react-native-scrollview, nativemethodsmixin

How can you measure the height of a react-native element if you only have the `ref`?

I see [NativeMethodsMixin](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/nativemethodsmixin.html) but it's not clear how to implement it.

I've tried including it as:

```
import { NativeMethodsMixin } from 'react-native';
class Foo extends Component {
  mixins: [NativeMethodsMixin]
  measure(ref) {
    console.log(NativeMethodsMixin.measure(ref));
  }
  ...
}
```

but the app complains that `NativeMethodsMixin` is undefined.

If I go the `RCTUIManager` route:

```
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';
const RCTUIManager = NativeModules.UIManager;
class Foo extends Component {
  measure(ref) {
    const height = RCTUIManager.measure(ref, (x, y, width, height, pageX, pageY) => height));
    console.log(height);
  }
  ...
}
```

then I get an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON`

I just want to get the height of that `ref`. What am I missing?

Comment: For anyone that finds this — you have to use a `ref`, and not the actual React backing class instance. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html

Answer (score -1):

You can do like this:

```
    this.refs[your ref key].measure((fx, fy, width, height, px, py) => {
          this.state.origins.push({
            x: px,
            y: py,
            width,
            height,
          });
        });
```

this link maybe helpful:[click here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/953)